# Mongoose discriminator not calling parent pre save hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have 2 models:

Transaction.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const { User } = require('./index');

const TransactionSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    amount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    userAmount: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }

}, { discriminatorKey: 'kind' });

TransactionSchema.pre('save', async function () {
    console.log('entered here?');
    const user = await User.findById(this.user);
    const modifier = this.kind == 'INCOME' ? 1 : -1;
    const amount = user.balance + (modifier * this.amount);
    this.userAmount = amount;
    user.balance = amount;
    await user.save();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Transaction', TransactionSchema);
```

Income.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Transaction = require('./Transaction');

const Income = Transaction.discriminator('INCOME', new Schema({
    client: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Client'
    }
}))

module.exports = Income;
```

As you can see, Income is discriminator of Transaction.
Now I defined pre save hook on Transaction, but when I call ***Income.create()***, that hook is never called, and I just get the error: **userAmount is required** (which I wanna set inside pre save).